# mysql query calculate rating sum

Tags: php, mysql, sql, count

I have following table

```
id item_id rating 
 1    10     1
 2    10     2
 3    10     2
 4    10     3
 5    10     3
 6    10     3
 7    10     4
```

How can I write a query so that I can get result as follows:

```
$ratings = array(
    1 => 1,
    2 => 2,
    3 => 3,
    4 => 1,
    5 => 0
);
```

I need to use this query to write a php function to calculate average ratings by this function:

```
$total = 0;
$count = 0;
foreach($ratings as $number=>$frequency) {
  $total += $number * $frequency;
  $count += $frequency;
}
return $total / $count;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The basic `COUNT`ing of records on the table won't produce `5` because there is no value `5` on the rating. But generating subquery which contains values from `1-5` and joining them using `LEFT JOIN` will do your desired result.

```
SELECT a.rating, COUNT(b.rating) totalCount
FROM
    (
      SELECT 1 rating UNION SELECT 2 UNION
      SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION
      SELECT 5
    ) a
    LEFT JOIN tableName b
      ON a.rating = b.rating
GROUP BY a.rating
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f879a/1)

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT
    rating,
    COUNT(rating) as Count
FROM rating
GROUP BY rating
```

Comment: hi, this is the simpliest query to solve the problem so far but it will not show rating 5 because it is not on the list. `:D`